# storing classmethod reference in tuple does not work as in variable

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Bar(object):

  @staticmethod
  def ruleOn(rule):
    if isinstance(rule, tuple):
      print rule[0]
      print rule[0].__get__(None, Foo)
    else:
      print rule

class Foo(object):

  @classmethod
  def callRule(cls):
    Bar.ruleOn(cls.RULE1)
    Bar.ruleOn(cls.RULE2)


  @classmethod
  def check(cls):
    print "I am check"

  RULE1   = check
  RULE2   = (check,)

Foo.callRule()
```

**Output:**

```
<bound method type.check of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
<classmethod object at 0xb7d313a4>
<bound method type.check of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
```

As you can see I'm trying to store a reference to a classmethod function in a tuple for future use.

However, it seems to store the object itself rather then reference to the bound function.

As you see it works for a variable reference.

The only way to get it is to use `__get__`, which requires the name of the class it belongs to, which is not available at the time of the `RULE` variable assignment.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because method are actually functions in Python. They only become bound methods when you look them up on the constructed class instance. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852308/how-the-method-resolution-and-invocation-works-internally-in-python/870650#870650) for more details. The non-tuple variant works because it is conceptually the same as accessing a classmethod.

If you want to assign bound classmethods to class attributes you'll have to do that after you construct the class:

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def callRule(cls):
        Bar.ruleOn(cls.RULE1)
        Bar.ruleOn(cls.RULE2)

    @classmethod
    def check(cls):
        print "I am check"

 Foo.RULE1 = Foo.check
 Foo.RULE2 = (Foo.check,)
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense.

Just out of curiosity
Is there any way to retrieve class name during its construction?

Comment: No. The class object doesn't exist while the class body is executing. The best you could do is to bind the functions using a class decorator or a metaclass.