# How does assignment of a function as a class attribute become a method in Python?

Tags: python, class-method

```
>>> class A(object): pass
>>> def func(cls): pass
>>> A.func = func
>>> A.func
<unbound method A.func>
```

How does this assignment create a method? It seems unintuitive that assignment does the following for classes:

- Turn functions into unbound instance methods
- Turn functions wrapped in `classmethod()` into class methods (actually, this is pretty intuitive)
- Turn functions wrapped in `staticmethod()` into functions

It seems that for the first, there should be an `instancemethod()`, and for the last one, there shouldn't be a wrapper function at all. I understand that these are for uses within a `class` block, but why should they apply outside of it?

But more importantly, how exactly does assignment of the function into a class work? What magic happens that resolves those 3 things?

Even more confusing with this:

```
>>> A.func
<unbound method A.func>
>>> A.__dict__['func']
<function func at 0x...>
```

But I think this is something to do with descriptors, when *retrieving* attributes. I don't think it has much to do with the *setting* of attributes here.

Comment: You are forgetting that instance methods are just instance variables that hold a function whose first argument is the instance itself.

Comment: What on God's doodoo is an instance variable?!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-accesshttp://gaijin.dmst.aueb.gr/~bkarak/weblog/2007/13112007.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that this has something to do with descriptor protocol. Descriptors are how passing the receiver object as the first parameter of a method is implemented in Python. You can read more detail about Python attribute lookup from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852308/how-the-method-resolution-and-invocation-works-internally-in-python/870650#870650). The following shows on a bit lower level, what is happening when you do A.func = func; A.func:

```
# A.func = func
A.__dict__['func'] = func # This just sets the attribute
# A.func
#   The __getattribute__ method of a type object calls the __get__ method with
#   None as the first parameter and the type as the second.
A.__dict__['func'].__get__(None, A) # The __get__ method of a function object
                                    # returns an unbound method object if the
                                    # first parameter is None.
a = A()
# a.func()
#   The __getattribute__ method of object finds an attribute on the type object
#   and calls the __get__ method of it with the instance as its first parameter.
a.__class__.__dict__['func'].__get__(a, a.__class__)
#   This returns a bound method object that is actually just a proxy for
#   inserting the object as the first parameter to the function call.
```

So it's the looking up of the function on a class or an instance that turns it into a method, not assigning it to a class attribute.

`classmethod` and `staticmethod` are just slightly different descriptors, classmethod returning a bound method object bound to a type object and staticmethod just returns the original function.

Comment: Thanks I think this is the most correct answer here. I found a more detailed analysis here: http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html. The key (magic) here is that a function becomes a method when it is accessed, not set, and this happens by the `__get__` descriptor available on each function object. `classmethod` and `staticmethod` have different `__get__`, which "transform" the function into a class/static method. It just happens that the default `__get__` on functions acts as instance methods.

Answer (score 4):

[Descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) are the magic<sup>1</sup> that turns an ordinary function into a bound or unbound method when you retrieve it from an instance or class, since they’re all just functions that need different binding strategies. The `classmethod` and `staticmethod` decorators implement other binding strategies, and `staticmethod` actually just returns the raw function, which is the same behavior you get from a non-function `callable` object.

See [“User-defined methods”](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-824) for some gory details, but note this:

> Also notice that this transformation only happens for user-defined functions; other callable objects (and all non-callable objects) are retrieved without transformation.

So if you wanted this transformation for your own callable object, you could just wrap it in a function, but you could also write a descriptor to implement your own binding strategy.

Here’s the `staticmethod` decorator in action, returning the underlying function when it’s accessed.

```
>>> @staticmethod
... def f(): pass
>>> class A(object): pass
>>> A.f = f
>>> A.f
<function f at 0x100479398>
>>> f
<staticmethod object at 0x100492750>
```

Whereas a normal object with a `__call__` method doesn’t get transformed:

```
>>> class C(object):
...         def __call__(self): pass
>>> c = C() 
>>> A.c = c 
>>> A.c
<__main__.C object at 0x10048b890>
>>> c
<__main__.C object at 0x10048b890>
```

<sup>1</sup> The specific function is `func_descr_get` in [Objects/funcobject.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r264/Objects/funcobject.c?revision=75707&view=markup).

Answer (score 3):

What you have to consider is that in Python [**everything** is an object](http://diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html). By establishing that it is easier to understand what is happening. If you have a function `def foo(bar): print bar`, you can do `spam = foo` and call `spam(1)`, getting of course, `1`.

Objects in Python keep their instance attributes in a dictionary called `__dict__` with a "pointer" to other objects. As [functions in Python are objects as well](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=y050/demox), they can be assigned and manipulated as simple variables, passed around to other functions, etc. Python's implementation of object orientation takes advantage of this, and treats methods as attributes, as functions that are in the `__dict__` of the object.

Instance methods' [first parameter is always the instance object itself](http://www.siafoo.net/article/52#passing-self-manually), generally called `self` (but this could be called `this` or `banana`). When a method is called directly on the `class`, it is unbound to any instance, so you have to give it an instance object as the first parameter (`A.func(A())`). When you call a [bound function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static) (`A().func()`), the first parameter of the method, `self`, is implicit, but behind the curtains Python does exactly the same as calling directly on the unbound function and passing the instance object as the first parameter.

If this is understood, the fact that assigning `A.func = func` (which behind the curtains is doing `A.__dict__["func"] = func`) leaves you with an unbound method, is unsurprising.

In your example the `cls` in `def func(cls): pass` actually what will be passed on is the instance (`self`) of type `A`. When you apply the [`classmethod`](http://pyref.infogami.com/classmethod) or [`staticmethod`](http://www.techexperiment.com/2008/08/21/creating-static-methods-in-python/) [decorators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) do nothing more than take the first argument obtained during the call of the function/method, and transform it into something else, before calling the function.

`classmethod` takes the first argument, gets the `class` object of the instance, and passes that as the first argument to the function call, while `staticmethod` simply discards the first parameter and calls the function without it.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1: The function `func` you defined exists as a [First-Class Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_object) in Python.

Point 2: Classes in Python store their attributes in their `__dict__`.

So what happens when you pass a function as the value of a class attribute in Python? That function is stored in the class' `__dict__`, making it a method of that class accessed by calling the attribute name you assigned it to.

Comment: The question is *how* does it make it a method of that class? What's special about it that `A.a = 3` doesn't do?

Comment: @MTsoul, the difference is that `callable(func)` is `True`, but `callable(3)` is `False`.

Comment: @gnibbler That's not it — creating an object with a `__call__` method doesn't trigger this.

Answer (score 0):

Relating to MTsoul's comment to Gabriel Hurley's answer:

What is different is that `func` has a `__call__()` method, making it "callable", i.e. you can apply the `()` operator to it. Check out [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) (search for `__call__` on that page).

Comment: No, an object with a `__call__` method doesn't get magically transformed into an `instancemethod`.

Comment: @jleedev: it doesn't turn it into an instance method, but into a callable. Being a callable that is an attribute of an object *does* turn it into instance method.

Comment: @voyager http://codepad.org/eOI0Hf88 Callable just means it has a `__call__` method, but the actual method binding is handled by descriptors. See my answer.