# Subtle unexpected behaviour with a function used as class-attribute

Tags: python, class-attributes

I have a piece of code that was broken when I changed an attribute and made it class-attribute, I would love to understand why.

So, I started with

```
def linInterp(x1, x2, y1, y2, x):
    return y1 + (x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

class Inter1DLineal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.interpSegment = linInterp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inter = Inter1DLineal()
    print(inter.interpSegment(0.2, 0.6, 0, 1, 0.4))
```

which works alright. I know I could implement `interpSegment` as a proper method in `Inter1DLineal`, for instance as

```
@classmethod
def interpSegment(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    return linInterp(*args, **kwargs)
```

but I thought I was fine with an attribute of type function.

What surprised me was what happened next. I decided that, because `interpSegment` is common to all instances, I should make it a class attribute.

```
def linInterp(x1, x2, y1, y2, x):
    return y1 + (x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

class Inter1DLineal(object):
    interpSegment = linInterp
    def __init__(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inter = Inter1DLineal()
    print(inter.interpSegment(0.2, 0.6, 0, 1, 0.4))
```

But this broke the code. It seems the call to `interpSegment` is passing now passing 6 attributes, not 5. Can someone explain why this happens? What would the most Pythonistic way of doing this?

Comment: Why does it need to be on the class at all? It accesses/affects neither the class nor an instance.

Comment: See [How does assignment of a function as a class attribute become a method in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2307653/222914)

Comment: @Ignacio of course you are right, this is just a toy example to show the behaviour I do not understand.

Comment: @JanneKarila thanks, I see that is exactly what underlies my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you are passing the `inter` as the first parameter which is the `self` parameter. So essentially, in the `"__main__"` code, you are passing something as follows:

`interpSegment(inter, 0.2, 0.6, 0, 1, 0.4)`

You should instead call it as:

`Inter1DLineal.interpSegment(0.2, 0.6, 0, 1, 0.4)`

However, let me also state that what you were doing first where `interpSegment` was in `__init__` or as a method on its own is a better way of doing it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Of course you are right. But what is still a bit mystifying is why the same call works in one case, and not in the other. Hopefully I will understand better when I read the post suggested by Janne. Anyway, I will go for implementing interpSegment as a method.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of help