# Can't access Python function as attribute

Tags: function, class, attributes, python-2.x

Imagine I have the following test.py file

```
import foo

class example1(object):
      MyFunc = foo.func
```

Where foo.py is

```
def func():
      return 'Hi'
```

Then I write another file

```
import test

test.example1.MyFunc()
```

and get the error 'unbound method func() must be called with example1 instance as first argument (got nothing instead)'.

How can I use the function func as an attribute of the class example1?

Comment: The above error is Python2 specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Python2 issue. Change `test.py` to the following and it works.

```
import foo

class example1(object):
    MyFunc = staticmethod(foo.func)
```

Note that if you keep `test.py` as you show it, the following works:

```
test.example1.__dict__['MyFunc']()
```

This is related to the way function attributes are accessed in Python. Have a look at [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol) if you feel curious.

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321744/python-function-as-class-attribute-becomes-a-bound-method). And [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307653/how-does-assignment-of-a-function-as-a-class-attribute-become-a-method-in-python)

The technicalities of the question are developped [here](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#new-attribute-access)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a python 2 specific problem. The type `unbound method` is deprecated in python 3. So your code is fine for python 3. Here is a well viewed answer on: [What is the difference between a function, an unbound method and a bound method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method). Calling a unbound method in python 2 will require an instance of the corresponding class type.

There are some solutions here. Another one is, you can define your function like this:

```
def func(object):
    return "Hi"
```

As this is taking object as its first argument. Now you can write this code:

```
test.example1().MyFunc()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in Python 2.7:

You are missing an `__init__()` method in your class definition.

foo.py should be defined as follows:

```
def func():
      return 'Hi'
```

The class should be defined as follows:

```
import foo

class example1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.MyFunc = foo.func
```

Then when you want to call attributes from the class you should instantiate it first. The tester.py script should look like this, for example:

```
import tester

testerInstance = tester.example1()

testerAttribute = testerInstance.MyFunc()
print testerAttribute
```