# How to pass variables to getattr

Tags: python

I need to call a class method by name, and pass any arguments. Below is an example of what I am try to do:

```
class C:
    def m(self, s, l=1):
        return "result"
    
    def add(self, op, *args, **kwargs):
        xx = getattr(C, op)(*args, **kwargs)
        print(xx)

ss = C()
ss.add('m', 1, l=5)
```

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError: m() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

How to dynamically pass any argument to any method I call?

Comment: `getattr(self, op)`? Or make them static, as they don't use self anyway.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `self` instead of `C`.

```py
class C:
    def m(self, s, l=1):
        return "result"
    
    def add(self, op, *args, **kwargs):
        xx = getattr(self, op)(*args, **kwargs)
        print(xx)

ss = C()
ss.add('m', 1, l=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `self`. Every instance method that is not called using the syntax `instace.method()`, shall be called using the syntax `class.method(instance)`:

```py
class C:
    def m(self, s, l=1):
        return "result"
    
    def add(self, op, *args, **kwargs):
        xx = getattr(C, op)(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print(xx)

ss = C()
ss.add('m', 1, l=5)
```

Another way is to bind the method using `getattr(instance, op)` instead of `geattr(class, op)`:

```py
class C:
    def m(self, s, l=1):
        return "result"
    
    def add(self, op, *args, **kwargs):
        xx = getattr(self, op)(*args, **kwargs)
        print(xx)

ss = C()
ss.add('m', 1, l=5)
```

For more info about how this works: [Accessing methods via getattr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51858649/7884305).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to either

(a) use `getattr(self, op)(*args, **kwargs)`

That way you are calling the `instance` method.

-or-

(b) pass `self` explicitely to the `class` method of the class `C`

```
getattr(C, op)(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip `s` in `m()` or use `self` instead of `C` in `getattr`.

```
class C:
    def m(self, l=1):
        return "result"

    def add(self, op, *args, **kwargs):
        xx = getattr(C, op)(*args, **kwargs)
        print(xx)

ss = C()
ss.add('m', 1, l=5)
```

Or use

```
class C:
    def m(self,s, l=1):
        return "result"

    def add(self, op, *args, **kwargs):
        xx = getattr(self, op)(*args, **kwargs)
        print(xx)

ss = C()
ss.add('m', 1, l=5)
```