# Can I create an object that receives arbitrary method invocation in python?

Tags: python, method-invocation

In python, can I create a Class that, when instantiated, can receive arbitrary method invocation? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852308/how-the-method-resolution-and-invocation-works-internally-in-python) but couldn't put the pieces together

I guess it has something to do with the `attribute lookup`. For a class `Foo`:

```
class Foo(object):
  def bar(self, a):
    print a
```

The class attribute can be obtained by `print Foo.__dict__`, which gives

```
{'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__module__': '__main__', 'bar': <function bar at 0x7facd91dac80>, '__doc__': None}
```

So this code is valid

```
foo = Foo()
foo.bar("xxx")
```

If I call `foo.someRandomMethod()`, `AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'someRandomMethod'` would be resulted.

I want `foo` object to receive any random invocations and defaults to no-op, ie.

```
def func():
    pass
```

How can I achieve this? I want this behaviour to mock an object for testing.

Comment: If you want to mock an object, why don't you use the Mock library, which does exactly this?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Your suggestion is totally the right way, I just want to know more the internal workings of python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Respond_to_an_unknown_method_call#Python

```
class Example(object):
    def foo(self):
        print("this is foo")
    def bar(self):
        print("this is bar")
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def method(*args):
            print("tried to handle unknown method " + name)
            if args:
                print("it had arguments: " + str(args))
        return method

example = Example()

example.foo()        # prints “this is foo”
example.bar()        # prints “this is bar”
example.grill()      # prints “tried to handle unknown method grill”
example.ding("dong") # prints “tried to handle unknown method ding”
                     # prints “it had arguments: ('dong',)”
```

Comment: `method` signature should take `*args, **kwargs` as an argument.